# how to make java content in center and size based on content

Tags: java, swing, javafx

When I run this project not in full-screen, the content is cut off on the right. 
[image: run in window]

When run in maximized window, the content is complete, but not centered.
[image: run in fullscreen]

What I want is it will be in the center of the screen and all content can be seen.

```
public DataCuti() {
    initComponents();
    Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    setLocation((dim.width / 2) - (getSize().width / 2), (dim.height / 2) - (getSize().height / 2));
    tampilTabel();
    tampilTabel2();
    tanggal();
    table.setEnabled(false);
}
```

Comment: Normally you shouldn't need to bother such things. If you correctly call `repack()` in the end the automatic sizing should be such that everything is on screen (as long as you don't exceed any max-size settings). Note that, when manually computing sizes, you need to add the size of the **title bar** to your computations. The title bar is not included inside the content window size but in the overall size. There are methods to dynamically get its size. It's about 10px I think.

Comment: Post your layout code. Is this a `Swing` node embedded in `JavaFX`?

Comment: The problem is your layout manager. I have never seen a layout manager that will align components to the right by default. You could use a GridBagLayout. The first row would have two panels each taking one cell and the second row would contain the table and span two cells. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use GridBagLayout]() for more information and working examples.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not changing any sizes of your widgets when you expand to a full-screen, you could perhaps fix the size meaning that the user could not expand the window. To do that you could try put this in the constructor of the frame:

```
setResizable(false);
```

Comment: it worked, but still theres a content that cut a bit. I made the other frame but its not like this, is it cause I made so many tables?

or how to make it fullscreen from the first, but the content in center of the frame? all I found in internet was how to make it in center of the screen